# SignIn with LinkedIn integration to android issue

Tags: linkedin-api, android-signing

I am android developer and i need to integrate the sign in with LinkedIn in my android application.
As per the documentation in developer.linkedin, i did each and every step.
But when i am testing the application on other phone then it appears like i need to register that separate phone package hash key to developer account and update it so that user can login else user will get an error while login with linked in
Is it compulsory to generate package-hash-key every time and register it into developer account to authenticate the user?

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to add your signing hash key and package name in the developer console of LinkedIn.

When running your app in debug mode or from Android studio, your signing hash is different from the release hash.

You can get the debug key on linux/mac like

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

You can add multiple rows on the linkedin app page.

```
com.packagename:releasekey
com.packagename:debugkey
```

[image]

Comment: yes, when i am generating hash key while testing is different for each phone but then how to make every phone authenticate and let then sign in with linked in? How to generate tje release and debug key in windows and dow i need to register and update these release and debug key in linkedin developer account ? @Mars

Comment: It's not different for each phone. It's different for each android studio setup, so your pc and that of your co-developers will generate different hash keys.

Comment: So now how to generate hash key for global users and register it on linkedin developer account using my windows pc?

Comment: To generate a hashkey for the public released app, run that command on the release keystore instead of debug keystore, you can follow directions on the Android developer site on how to generate a release keystore first. After that build and sign the apk with that keystore.

Comment: didnt get the hash key.
only got : Creation date: X
Entry type: X
Certificate chain length: 1
Certificate[1]:
Owner: CN=X..X, OU=X..X, O=X..X X..X, L=X..X, ST=X..X, C=X
Issuer: CN=X..X, OU=X..X, O=X..X..X, L=X..X, ST=X..X, C=X
Serial number: X..X
Valid from: Fri Nov X until: Tue Apr X
Certificate fingerprints: 
         MD5:  X......X
         SHA1: X.......X
         SHA256: X.....X
         Signature algorithm name: X..X
         Version: 3
Extensions:
#1: ObjectId: X Criticality=X
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
.
.
]
]

Comment: Sha1 is your hash

Comment: i generate the release hash key from terminal but its not working with linked in :(